# Add "Go to App" Button to Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I have the following page:

https://www.facebook.com/LetsMapp

I want to add the "Go to App button", like this Page has:

https://www.facebook.com/iframesapp

How do I do this?

My current settings:

```
Basic Info
Display Name: LetsMapp

Namespace: letsmapp

Contact Email: mb@conchain.com

App Domains: letsmapp.com

Category: Communication

Hosting URL: You have not generated a URL through one of our partners (Get one)
Sandbox Mode: Disabled

Select how your app integrates with Facebook
Website with Facebook Login
Site URL: http://letsmapp.com/

App on Facebook
Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/letsmapp
Canvas URL: http://letsmapp.com/canvas/
Secure Canvas URL: https://letsmapp.com/canvas/
Bookmark URL:

Canvas Width: Fixed (760px)
Canvas Height: Fluid

Native iOS App
iOS Bundle ID: conchain
iPhone App Store ID: 483192608
iPad App Store ID: 0

Configured for iOS SSO: Enabled
iOS Native Deep Linking: Enabled
URL Scheme Suffix:

Page Tab
Page Tab Name: LetsMapp
Page Tab URL: http://letsmapp.com/canvas/
Secure Page Tab URL: https://letsmapp.com/canvas/
Page Tab Edit URL:
```

Answer (score 0):

To have "Go to App" button on your Facebook Page your associated application need Site/Canvas URL to be specified in settings.

Comment: Where do I set this?
My current settings are in my first post.

Comment: @MariuszB. Choose the desired page as associated to application in application settings (**App Page** field of **App Details** section)\